# Mapbox: Display div overlay while keeping map controls

Tags: css, mapbox-gl-js

I'm making a app with mapbox-gl-js and I'm having trouble setting up a `div` overlay that still allow to control the map underneath.

I tried setting `pointer-events: none` on the overlay div, that worked, but only if the div's position is set to `fixed` or `absolute` and I want the position to be `relative`.

How can I do that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Show an example of the code. For example, on the jsfiddle.

Comment: @stdob-- Here is an example https://codesandbox.io/s/oj3nkxm72q , I would like to be able to control the map through the red overlay so disable all interaction on the overlay and let them be handled by the map underneath

Answer (score 2):

You need:

- change the order of the blocks: first a map, then an overlay.
- remove `zIndex: -1` from the map style
- add `pointer-events: all` to the overlay button

[ https://codesandbox.io/s/2v4p9r1o0j ]